# Unable to test any code using an openlayers' module in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs, openlayers-5

I'm trying to write some tests for some modules that happen to import an openlayers module or two. But as some others have found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300919/how-to-transform-module-after-ordinary-transform-has-run-in-jest), [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7401), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971729/how-to-test-a-component-containing-openlayers-map-using-createreactapp)), this doesn't work out of the box. Here's what I've tried:

- renaming `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` and exporting the config
- added `transformIgnorePatterns` to my `jest.config.js`

I'm just at a loss as to what would fix this now.

I'm using:

- Non-CRA webpack config
- Jest v23.6.0
- babel-core 6.26.3
- typescript 3.1.3
- ts-jest 22.4.6

Here's my configs:

Jest:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: [
    "./testConfig/test-shim.js",
    "./testConfig/test-setup.js"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?!(ol)/).*/",
    "node_modules/(?!(ol)/)",
  ],
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx|tsx?)$",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^(Controllers|Api|Utilities)/(.*)$": "<rootDir>Scripts/$1/$2"
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  coverageReporters: ["text", "text-summary", "html"],
  coverageDirectory: "testConfig/coverageReport",
  collectCoverageFrom: ["**/Scripts/{App,Controllers,Utilities,Localization,EntryPoints}/**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 0,
      functions: 0,
      lines: 0,
      statements: 0
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got this working, finally. The problem was that the project was using TypeScript and, as usual, that made things far more complicated than it needed to be.

Since the OL sources needed to be compiled, and those files are written in JavaScript, I needed to add another transform to my config to just handle those files. After that, it complained about canvas, so I had to also install a canvas mock.

So the changed portion of my config is as follows:

```
  setupFiles: [
    "./testConfig/test-shim.js",
    "jest-canvas-mock", // <- the new mock
    "./testConfig/test-setup.js"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest", // <- also compile js/x files
  },
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(ol)/)", // <- exclude the OL lib
  ],
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I'm having the same issues!  Would you be able to post some of the contents of your other config files?

Comment: I came across this issue **on a CRA application also with Typescript** where the test script was `react-scripts test` while **testing a component that used Openlayers' components other than map**. After searching for CRA-specific solutions, trying what @jktravis suggests (which thankfully put me on the right trail) I solved the **somewhat similar** issue by changing the CLI command to `react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!(ol)/)/\"`. I post this comment hoping it will help others in the future since Google brought me to this question.